# Find ordered bases $B$, $C$ of a linear transformation satisfying a condition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let $D: \mathbb {R}_{\le n} [x] \to {R}_{\le n} [x]$ defined as $D\ (p(x)) = p'(x)$.

Find ordered bases $B$, $C$ of ${R}_{\le n} [x]$ such that $[D]_{C}^{B} = J$ while J being the following matrix:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&\cdots &0\\0&1&\cdots &0\\\vdots &\vdots &\ddots &\vdots \\0&0&\cdots &0\end{bmatrix}$$

The main diagonal are ones except the last element in the diagonal which is zero.

I don't know how to approach this problem so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $(x^n,x^{n-1},\ldots,x,1)$ as the first basis and $(nx^{n-1},(n-1)x^{n-2},\ldots,2x,1,x^n)$ as the second basis. Since

- $D(x^n)=x^{n-1}$;
- $D(x^{n-1})=(n-1)x^{n-2}$;
- …
- $D(x)=1$;
- $D(1)=0$

it will do what you want.